# jQuery $.ajax POST url randomly doesn't respond - no errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"items-list.php",
  data:{u:encodeURIComponent(u)}
})
.done(function(h){
    console.log('completed');
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown); // displays nothing
})
```

The code above randomly fails.  There is no http response on these failures (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JEOa.jpg) There is no error, although the `.fail()` function does get set-off after ~7 seconds.

All the request headers are exactly the same. The failures, when they happen are never at the same point - they are completely random from what I can see. Any insight into what might cause this type of issue? PHP setting? AJAX weirdness?

EDIT:
I do see that the network tab shows 'type' as plain, while all the others show 'html'. But there is no response, and there are no errors, as indicated from the imgur image. Both waiting and receiving are 0.

Comment: I think we need more context here, perhaps a snippet from developer console.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: Also, whats going on the server side?

Comment: @AlexanderDavydov it's fetching 25 rows from a MySQL database. No PHP errors, no DB errors. It literally just doesn't appear to respond at all in these instances.

Comment: @epascarello I see that it doesn't respond at all.. No code, no errors. The only difference is 'type' is plain while the others that succeed are html. Not sure if this is indicative of anything other than it not responding.

Comment: Is this issue reproduce-able or does it only occur once in a blue moon?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it occurs often enough that I can reproduce it if I keep at it, but it occurs randomly so there's no set way to consistently reproduce it.

Comment: For starters: `data:{u:encodeURIComponent(u))}` should be `data:{u:encodeURIComponent(u)}`. You have too many closing parentheses.

Comment: If that doesn't fix your issue then make sure that `items-list.php` has `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the file.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that was a typo on my part... doesn't exist in actual code. corrected.

Comment: Does anything show up in your server's error logs or PHP's error logs?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, nope, no errors either in PHP nor Server error logs. The network just seens to indicate that it doesn't connect at all. There are no http responses or anything.

Comment: Check the access logs as well